# How can I configure Webpack 4 to automatically import split chunks when a bundle is requested via script tag?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

I have been pulling my hair out for 3 weeks trying to get this to work, and I can't figure out where the gap in my understanding is.

I am building a library of components for an authorable CMS. My vision is to have a set of *n* thin entrypoints, all of which will have statically imported dependencies that are requested when the entrypoint is run via script tag.

Per my understanding, webpack can chunk shared dependencies together via splitChunks plugin, and those dependencies can be automatically loaded via the bundle-loader plugin.

However, when I call an entrypoint bundle via script tag, the automatic dependency import does not occur - only when I use dynamic import() syntax within my source files does dynamic import occur - but that's because import() itself is dynamic.

How can I configure webpack to pull in statically dependent chunks?

Comment: Show us some code of what you have done so far

Comment: That would be helpful, wouldn't it? Put together a repo here, thanks for taking a look :)
https://github.com/teolitto/webpack-splitchunks-auto-import

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Paragons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-paragons) (see section: **Code Splitting**). Then take a look at [CodeSplitPage](https://github.com/joseki-tech/generator-paragons/blob/master/generators/app/templates/paragons-template/src/shared/demo/components/CodeSplitPage.js) which is wrapped in a Loadable using a dynamic import.

Answer (score 0):

The [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) is what you're looking for. You can configure it to generate `entry.html` output files in your `dist` folder, which you can then use in an Express application, or import into your non-Node server rendering to get the full list of `<script>` tag.